# Guuuurl, I **love** that flower

Tags: riddle, word

I can sit on your head, or maybe your hand;
I look like I came from a different land.
Find me in water, or perhaps above,
I'll give your prized flower some lovely, lovely **love**.

I can be a snack, but I'd prefer if you don't,
in fact, I'd prefer to stay unknown.
My cousin of mine, to make a correction:
He's simply ain't got no protection!
I can be male, or I can be female-
but I'll still remain a simple little* _____.

*<sub>In most cases.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> a snail?

I can sit on your head, or maybe your hand;

> they're small enough to do so, also this could be a Gary reference

I look like I came from a different land.

> they do look pretty weird

Find me in water, or perhaps above,

> there are sea snails and also tree snails

I'll give your prized flower some lovely, lovely love.

> snails love to eat flowers

I can be a snack, but I'd prefer if you don't,

> did you see that 'S' car go??

in fact, I'd prefer to stay unknown.

> they'd probably rather not be cooked in a white wine and garlic sauce, with or without melted cheese on top

My cousin of mine, to make a correction:

> a slug, possibly?

He's simply ain't got no protection!

> slugs don't have shells

I can be male, or I can be female-

> snails are hermaphrodites, and can act as male or female for the purposes of reproduction

but I'll still remain a simple little* _____.

> and snail rhymes with female!

Comment: To quote Robert Benchley: "Sometimes they are male, sometimes they are female and sometimes, on rainy days, they just drift."